# JQuery get value from a Ajax response

Tags: jquery

I use Ajax to call a PHP script.  This then returns an array of data.
Now if I do the following:

```
.done(function( response ) {
    if(response === false || response === 'false') {
        $('.main-container').css('display', 'none');
        $('.invalidRow').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.main-container').css('display', 'block');
        $('#emailAddress').append(response.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
    }
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus  ) {
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

The output is

> array(4) { [0]=> string(19) myemail@email.com [1]=> string(11) 778765 
>   }

So it outputs the whole response as expected.  However, if I change it to

```
response[0].replace(/['"]+/g, '')
```

It only prints out a (from the word array).  I am trying to get it to print out myemail@email.com.  How can I do this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
My response is now

> [myemail@email.com,12345,myname,mysurname]

How do I get these individual values?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to check if the return is a string or a boolean, you might be doing something wrong. If your return string is false and not a boolean, you're definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: Please post your PHP script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to parse the JSON string and access its values.

```
.done(function( response ) {
    if(response === false || response === 'false') {
        $('.main-container').css('display', 'none');
        $('.invalidRow').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
        // then access it like any normal javascript object.
        $('.main-container').css('display', 'block');
        $('#emailAddress').append(response.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
    }
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus  ) {
    console.log(textStatus);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the PHP Script outputs a var_dump instead of the data. Consider using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) in your PHP function and then on the client side process the response with [JSON.parse()](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/json/parse).

Comment: I have updated the OP after making your suggestion, thanks